# Finding the index at which upon removing element string becomes palindrome

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing the solution to this HackerRank problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index

I've tried this code:

```
T = int(raw_input())

for t in xrange(T):
    s = raw_input()
    index = -1
    if s != s[::-1]:
        for i in xrange(len(s)):
            temp = s[:i:] + s[i+1::]
            if temp == temp[::-1]:
                index = i
                break
    print index
```

But when I submit it, out of the 14 test cases, around 8 take a long time to compute (~5-7 seconds) and 1 of them takes more than 10 seconds, so HackerRank doesn't even show the result (whether it gave the right output).
It seems my code is inefficient. Please help me out in making it run faster.

Comment: Do you have an idea for the size of these strings? The `s[::-1]` would cause some slowness if it's a large object (it produces a copy in place, O(n))

Comment: @AlexO'Neill 100005 chars

Comment: Yes, as @Ivo noted, it's over a 100,000 characters. I guess that's why the last few test cases take so much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to speed the code would be to remove slicing for every index in case that string isn't a palindrome. In case of maximum length string which is not a palindrome following line will generate over 200000 slices: `temp = s[:i:] + s[i+1::]`.

You could start checking the string from start and beginning until you spot a difference. Once found you can generate slice which has either first or last letter removed and check if that's a palindrome. In case you removed the first character and result wasn't a palindrome you know that last character is the correct solution since the problem statement guarantees that:

```
T = int(raw_input())

for t in xrange(T):
    s = raw_input()
    length = len(s)
    for i in xrange(length / 2):
        if s[i] != s[length - i - 1]:
            if s[i + 1:length - i] == s[length - i - 1:i:-1]:
                print i
            else:
                print length - i - 1
            break
    else:
        print -1
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way would be to check from both sides left and right and break on inequality:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    s=input()
    if s==s[::-1]:
        print(-1)
    else:
        for i in range(int(len(s)/2)):
            if s[i]!=s[len(s)-1-i]:
                print(i if ((s[:i]+s[i+1:])==(s[:i]+s[i+1:])[::-1]) else len(s)-1-i)
                break
```

Apparently I'm a member of that site as well, executed my code and it passes all test cases with 0.01 s and 0.02s

Answer (score 0):

I think returning the index of the element on the right without checking if its removal produces a palindrome it is a bad idea

```
index = -1
for i in range(len(s)//2):
    if s[i] != s[-1-i]:
        if s[:i]+s[i+1:] == (s[:i]+s[i+1:])[::-1]:
            index = i
        else:
            if i > 0:
                if s[:-1-i]+s[-1-i+1:] == (s[:-1-i]+s[-1-i+1:])[::-1]:
                    index = len(s) -1 -i
            else:
                if s[:-1-i] == (s[:-1-i])[::-1]:
                    index = len(s) -1 -i
        break
return index
```

Comment: This is opinion based. Does not provide an effective answer.

Comment: @Karl-Marx using this string 'hgygsvlfcXwnswtuhmyaljkqlqjjqlqkjlaymhutwsnwcwflvsgygh' you can test that in fact returning the right element without checking produces wrong result since it is not a palindrome.

Comment: This is the kind of info you should include in the answer. The answer might be right, but the way it is composed reads like an opinion. A good answer on SO should be justified and contextualized.